# struct inside #ifndef greyed out and inaccessible by other source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a struct inside an ifndef, which is greyed out in visual studio. It is located in a header file which is then included in another cpp file. The cpp file cannot access the struct, and it causes compile errors.

I have added the definition, which is GAME_SHADER_DLL to the pre-processor definitions of the project in visual studio, yet not luck.

This is not my code, it is from source sdk 2013. I have got the code to work by removing the definitions, however I do not know what effect this will have, as I am not sussed on what definitions do in projects this large.

```cpp
// BaseVSShader.h
#ifndef GAME_SHADER_DLL

struct DrawFlashlight_dx90_Vars_t
{
    DrawFlashlight_dx90_Vars_t() 
    { 
        // set all ints to -1
        memset( this, 0xFF, sizeof(DrawFlashlight_dx90_Vars_t) ); 
        // set all bools to a default value.
        m_bBump = false;
        m_bLightmappedGeneric = false;
        m_bWorldVertexTransition = false;
        m_bTeeth = false;
        m_bSSBump = false;
        m_fSeamlessScale = 0.0;
    }
    bool m_bBump;
    bool m_bLightmappedGeneric;
    bool m_bWorldVertexTransition;
    bool m_bTeeth;
    int m_nBumpmapVar;
    int m_nBumpmapFrame;
    int m_nBumpTransform;
    int m_nFlashlightTextureVar;
    int m_nFlashlightTextureFrameVar;
    int m_nBaseTexture2Var;
    int m_nBaseTexture2FrameVar;
    int m_nBumpmap2Var;
    int m_nBumpmap2Frame;
    int m_nBump2Transform;
    int m_nDetailVar;
    int m_nDetailScale;
    int m_nDetailTextureCombineMode;
    int m_nDetailTextureBlendFactor;
    int m_nDetailTint;
    int m_nTeethForwardVar;
    int m_nTeethIllumFactorVar;
    int m_nAlphaTestReference;
    bool m_bSSBump;
    float m_fSeamlessScale;                             // 0.0 = not seamless
};
void DrawFlashlight_dx90( IMaterialVar** params, 
    IShaderDynamicAPI *pShaderAPI, IShaderShadow* pShaderShadow, DrawFlashlight_dx90_Vars_t &vars );

#endif // GAME_SHADER_DLL

// lightmappedgeneric_dx9_helper.cpp
#include "BaseVSShader.h"

// ... Further down in the file

CBaseVSShader::DrawFlashlight_dx90_Vars_t vars; // Has no member DrawFlashlight_dx90_Vars_t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have added the definition, which is GAME_SHADER_DLL to the pre-processor definitions of the project in visual studio

That means it's defined.

> `#ifndef GAME_SHADER_DLL`

This activates code if it's *not* defined.

Did you want `#ifdef` instead?

Comment: If you have a problem with some tool, look up its behaviour in _documentation_ to remind yourself of what it does. Only takes a few seconds.

Comment: Good point, that did not occur to me. Most files use ifndef for this definition but others use ifdef. It is inconsistent, but now I know what is going on I can fix that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The if**n**def directive keeps the source text **if** the macro argument is **not** defined.

> I have added the definition, which is GAME_SHADER_DLL

If you define the macro `GAME_SHADER_DLL`, then that `ifndef` directive will remove the text. So, if your intention is to not remove it, then you should do the opposite. In that case you need to make sure that `GAME_SHADER_DLL` macro is not defined.